# Retrieve text from JComboBox

Tags: java, combobox, jcombobox

How to retrieve Text that is typed in JComboBox. This text need not be an existing item.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get the selected or typed value from a JComboBox by calling method `getSelectedItem`. If it is not an existing item, then you'll get a String object. Otherwise you'll get whatever object you populated the combo box with.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use :

```
String value= comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Other examples available [here](http://tutoref.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
String typedText = ((JTextField)myComboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getText();
```